# Simulating mouse movement, without browser "head", to web server

Tags: c#, browser, screen-scraping

I need to connect to a website programmatically, but without rendering the browser view, and then query the "headless" browser for certain page element's coordinate positions and send JavaScript events to simulate the movement of a mouse across the page form its current location to the new location.

I already have found a method that "realistically" moves the mouse programmatically between two points. All I need to do now is find a library that will allow me to connect to a page without the GUI but includes the positions of the page elements, but still query the JavaScript of the page and send JavaScript to the page's browser instance.

I know this very specific, but it will allow us to simulate our pages and test PHP heat mapping of the mouse location. It is also vital that this is for C#. Does such a library exist for C#?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/)? This can be run in headless mode, and has a very powerful API. I've used in C# for automated testing (including Javascript manipulation), and it works very well. It should be fine for scraping too though.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on how to use this as a headless browser (any tutorials, examples, etc)? I did stumble onto it a couple of times, but I couldn't find how to do this

Comment: Unfortunately the code from when I did it is at my work, and I'm off work this week so don't have an example at hand. Doing a Google for "selenium headless .net" gives quite a few results though. Note that I haven't tested mouse interactivity in headless mode though.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'll check it out and mark this as the answer if it's what I needed!